# Angular not loading the styles completely

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I had followed the conventional method of including the style in the component. but **styles** are not reflected in the browser. However, only one property is reflected among many. if have **6** style properties in applied to a class only **1** property reflected.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'userbar',
  templateUrl: './userbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userbar.component.css']
})
export class UserbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

```css
#userbar #wallpicture {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/73/d5/d4/73d5d48c16adf342d4364d027053176b.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  border-top-left-radius: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: inherit;
  background-position: 0px 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
#userbar {
  width: 100%;
}
#userbar #profilepicture {
￼ border-radius: 50%;
￼ position: relative;
￼ left: -webkit-calc(100% - 350px);
  left: -moz-calc(100% - 350px);
￼ left: calc(50% - 32px);
￼ top: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userbar">
  <div id="picturesection">
    <div id="wallpicture">
      <img id="profilepicture" src="/assets/images/general/userimage.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just added an answer. Looks like there were some invisible unicode characters in there at the start of each line that are messing up the CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some illegal characters in the CSS, specifically the  'OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (U+FFFC)

Remove all the blank characters at the start of each line, and replace them with spaces

It should be working in the snippet below. I've replaced the relative URL with an absolute URL just to test it.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'userbar',
  templateUrl: './userbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userbar.component.css']
})
export class UserbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

```css
#userbar #wallpicture {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/73/d5/d4/73d5d48c16adf342d4364d027053176b.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  border-top-left-radius: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: inherit;
  background-position: 0px 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
#userbar {
  width: 100%;
}
#userbar #profilepicture {
  border-radius: 50%;
￼  position: relative;
￼  left: -webkit-calc(100% - 350px);
  left: -moz-calc(100% - 350px);
￼  left: calc(50% - 32px);
￼  top: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userbar">
  <div id="picturesection">
    <div id="wallpicture">
      <img id="profilepicture" src="https://www.ienglishstatus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Cute-Whatsapp-DP.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your css.

**#userbar , #wallpicture**

```
#userbar, #wallpicture {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/73/d5/d4/73d5d48c16adf342d4364d027053176b.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  border-top-left-radius: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: inherit;
  background-position: 0px 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
#userbar {
  width: 100%;
}
#userbar, #profilepicture {
￼ border-radius: 50%;
￼ position: relative;
￼ left: -webkit-calc(100% - 350px);
  left: -moz-calc(100% - 350px);
￼ left: calc(50% - 32px);
￼ top: 64px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please, specifically let me know whats wrong in CSS?